# Obtener sesión desde un iframe CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de obtener la variable `$_SESSION` desde un iframe, pero siempre obtengo un array vacío. Para aclarar, estoy utilizando CodeIgniter como framework. He visto soluciones por medio de parámetros tipo GET, pero  por motivos de seguridad, NO puedo utilizarlo de esa forma. Si conocen una solución, les agradecería bastante. Les dejo algo de código para contextualizar.

Función del controlador.

```
public function geos()
{
    $this->is_logged_in();
    if (!$this->require_role('admin')) {
        redirect(LOGIN_PAGE);
    }
    $this->load->view('geos');
}
```

Vista 'geos'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>MiCCi GEOS</title>
    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html,body {
            min-height: 100vh;
        }
        iframe {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="<?= base_url() ?>geos/index.php" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Finalmente, el código del archivo cargado en el iframe. El archivo cargado  está localizado en el mismo dominio.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION); // Siempre imprime: Array()
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['httpUser']) || !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        echo "<h1>404 Not Found</h1>";
        echo "The page that you have requested could not be found.";
        die();
    }
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Si estás utilizando la librería session, tiene más sentido generar la vista del iframe desde codeigniter. Podrías recuperar la sessión con `$this->session->userdata('key')`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Bueno, en sí no entiendo la solución. Si puedes ser un poco más detallado te lo agradecería.